# Cannot connect to MSSQL Server after recent windows 10 updates

Tags: sql-server, networking, connection, database-connection

I am not able to connect to remote SQL Server from my machine, I don't know what went wrong but yesterday I was able to connect to remote server.

I can connect through Management Studio from my machine to remote sql server but I cannot connect through SQL Profiler.

Please see below screenshot for more info.

[image]

Comment: What version of SQL Server is it?

Comment: Judging by the instance name, I'd say 2014.

Comment: Yes SQL Server 2014

Comment: after recent windows 10 updates I started facing this issue...

Comment: Any updates? 
Having same issue, cannot connect to local instanse, using Windows authentification, I was able to connect via SQL autentification, but still it's a bammer...
Restoring instance wont help, I will try to reinstall server completely if no other solution will be found...

Answer (score 1):

If you faced with this issue after OS upgrade, it should be some environment change.
Check that SQL Server instance written correct and the instance is up (Administration - Services). Then check firewall rules - the easiest way is to temporary turn it off.

Comment: I checked everything ....but no success yet.. just now we have started facing same issue in our second machine... this is weird...after windows 10 updates...

Comment: Anyway, I'd bet on change of firewall rules.Is (local) connection available?

Comment: Also, did you try to connect via tcp/ip from the same computer to localhost?

Comment: firewall is completely off

Comment: Yes I can connect

Comment: So, it's definitely a firewall issue. I think that in Windows 10 firewall could not be completely off even if you did it. Try to allow connection to MS SQL port - it can help.